# Prove $((A^C \cup B^C) \setminus A)^C = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I have attempted this proof as outlined below. However, I feel that it is not correct, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Prove $((A^C \cup B^C) \setminus A)^C = A$

L.H.S. $((A^C \cup B^C) \setminus A)^C$

$= ((A^C \cup B^C) \cap A^C)^C$

$= (A^C \cup B^C)^C \cup A$

$= (A \cap B) \cup A$

$= A$

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely correct. You apply the fact that $C \setminus D = C \cap D^c$, which is "true by definition", and twice de Morgan (including $(A^c)^c = A$).

Comment: Absorption law too.

Comment: Thanks guys, it just *looked* tricky so I wasn't sure if I followed the correct process.